# Why my .net6 signalr server produce many log entries?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm new to SignalR. My .NET 6 SignalR server works fine with my .net client. But sometimes, server side produce many log entries like below. If I manually retart server, Server go back to normal and no such entries produced in log.

What are they? Why I got them every 15 seconds?

```
2022-09-30 17:20:02.847 +08:00 [INF] HTTP POST /parkingHub responded 200 in 0.1625 ms
2022-09-30 17:20:17.889 +08:00 [INF] HTTP POST /parkingHub responded 200 in 0.1524 ms
2022-09-30 17:20:33.887 +08:00 [INF] HTTP POST /parkingHub responded 200 in 0.5333 ms
2022-09-30 17:20:49.888 +08:00 [INF] HTTP POST /parkingHub responded 200 in 0.2478 ms
2022-09-30 17:21:05.876 +08:00 [INF] HTTP POST /parkingHub responded 200 in 0.6225 ms
2022-09-30 17:21:21.876 +08:00 [INF] HTTP POST /parkingHub responded 200 in 0.1872 ms
```

Comment: Have you enabled logging for signalR application?

Comment: Yes, I set loglevel to DEBUG. However, the point here is that the same loglevel setting, my only .net client can get connected most of time without seeing the logs like the above. Only rare times, server starts producing the above logs continuosly until I restart my server app.

Comment: this depends on how your client is connected to server. I mean to say which transport method your client is using. If your one client is connected through Long Polling method then this will send continues request to server after a very short interval i.e 1 sec. and the result is server will log all incoming request.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My real concern is that in production, I will have more than one hundreds of clients,(even hundreds of them), if most clients "ping" my server using Long Polling, my server will log much more the above success entries in log. Do you think that will hurt server's performance? By the way, most of time, the client use Websockets to connect to server, no such entries in log.

Comment: By forceing my client to use diferent Tansport protocols, I found the above log were produced when my client using Server-sent-events protocol.